# Can not create TokenAccount for WrappedSOL

Tags: web3.js, spl-token

I can not create a TokenAccount for WrappedSOL. Here is my code:

```
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'), 'confirmed');

const tokenAddress = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(new PublicKey('So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112'), wallet.publicKey);
const tokenAccount = await getAccount(connection, tokenAddress);

const transaction = new Transaction();

try {
    const account = await getAccount(connection, tokenAddress);
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof TokenAccountNotFoundError) {
        transaction.add(
            createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
                wallet.publicKey,
                tokenAddress,
                wallet.publicKey,
                new PublicKey('So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112')
            )
        );
    }
}

let signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    transaction,
    [wallet]
);
```

When I execute this I get the following error:

```
if (!info) throw new TokenAccountNotFoundError();
                     ^
TokenAccountNotFoundError
    at unpackAccount (/Users/stefan/Projects/solana-token/node_modules/@solana/spl-token/src/state/account.ts:170:22)
    at /Users/stefan/Projects/solana-token/node_modules/@solana/spl-token/src/state/account.ts:103:12
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/stefan/Projects/solana-token/node_modules/@solana/spl-token/lib/cjs/state/account.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Has anyone an idea why it does not work? With any other token it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In your fourth line of code
`const tokenAccount = await getAccount(connection, tokenAddress);`

The token account hasn’t been init yet, so the account info cannot be parsed in to a token account object which throws the error.

Move this line after the transaction is finalized.

A better way to check if it’s an token account will be:

Fetch the token account info, check if the account owner is Token program.